# Algorithm for filling space between points with color

Tags: c#, algorithm, 2d

I have points from arrays which looks like this after printing:
[image]

Points are printed based on three arrays: one with x coordinate, second with y coordinate and third with value for color .Now I need an algorith to fill space between those points. Important thing is I don't want to fill space between separate shapes. Is there any method for doing that except using concave hull (there is no implementation in c#)

edit: is it possible to somehow separate those areas and then use flood fill?

Answer (score 2):

How precise do you need the algorithm to be?

If you can tolerate some imprecision (a small area around the point shapes would be selected too), you could do with a blur.

It would go like this:

1) Blur the image with a small radius (equal to half of the maximum allowed distance between the points).

2) Each pixel that has color which is precisely equal to the background color is considered "outside" (each pixel with a different color is within a small disance to one of the darker points).

There is [BlueBitmapEffect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.bitmapeffectgroup(v=vs.90).aspx) in WPF, but that probably cannot be used in your scenario. You can find countless blur implementations online though.

If you need to be precise, you are out of luck in my opinion. Your goal is basically the definition of convex/concave hull.